# Didnt display results in database

Tags: mysql, database

I have a little problem with one database. I have already entered data in the individual tables in the database. The problem is that with this code, it displays the column names, but didnt return rows. I can't find the error. I think the problem is in JOIN itself. Any ideas for solving the problem?

```
SELECT cars.brand,
       cars.model,
       cars.yearofproduction,
       cars.engine_type,
       parts.part_name,
       parts.price AS MONEY,
       parts.quantity
FROM   CATALOG
       JOIN parts
            ON  parts.part_name = parts.id
       JOIN cars
            ON  CATALOG.car_id = cars.id
WHERE  quantity >= '0'
HAVING MONEY < (
           SELECT AVG(price)
           FROM   cars
       );
```

And here the tables. I've already insert values in the tables.

```
CREATE TABLE CATALOG.parts
(
    id              INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    part_name       VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    price           DECIMAL NOT NULL,
    DESCRIPTION     VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    quantity        TINYINT DEFAULT 0
);

CREATE TABLE CATALOG.cars
(
    id                   INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    brand                VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    model                VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    yearofproduction     YEAR NOT NULL,
    engine_type          SET('Diesel', 'A95', 'Gas', 'Metan')
);

CREATE TABLE CATALOG.catalog
(
    part_id     INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(part_id) REFERENCES parts(id) 
    ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    car_id      INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(car_id) REFERENCES cars(id) 
    ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY(part_id, car_id)
);
```

Comment: Maybe none of the parts have a price less than the average car price.

Comment: Show some sample data and the expected result.

Comment: It seems that one of your `join` is incorrect: `JOIN parts on parts.part_name=parts.id `. Maybe it should be `JOIN parts on catalog.part_id=parts.id` ?